# Java: How to assign variable value in a loop?

Tags: java

I have created timeslots for patient scheduling. I have made 160 of them for one week but I want thousand weeks, so for every timeslot I have made a variable week (int). Now for some reason, every timeslot gets the value 1000 for the variable week. If I test the same code on a test variable it works just fine. Anyone has an idea?

```
    int[] test = new int[160000];
    for(int j =0;j<1000;j++)
    {
      for(int i = 0;i < 160;i++)
     {
         timeslot[j*160 + i] = timeslot_build[i];
         timeslot[j*160 + i].set_week(j+1);
         test[j*160 + i] = (j+1);

     }      

    }


     System.out.println(test[150]);
     System.out.println(test[5166]);
     System.out.println(test[44000]);
     System.out.println(test[100000]); 

     System.out.println(timeslot[150].week);
     System.out.println(timeslot[5166].week);
     System.out.println(timeslot[44000].week);
     System.out.println(timeslot[100000].week);
```

This is the output:

1
33
276
626
1000
1000
1000
1000

Comment: How do you initialize `test`?

Comment: Could you provide timeslot, or check that timeslot.set_week does set the week field properly ?

Comment: What is `timeslot_build`? Why do you assign twice the week value to timeslot(.set_week and .week)?

Comment: Assigning this value twice is a mistake but it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Timeslot_build were the initial timeslots for only one week

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign `timeslot[j*160 + i] = timeslot_build[i]` you use same instance.

So `timeslot[0*160 + i]` = `timeslot[1*160 + i]` = `timeslot[2*160 + i]` etc.

You have to create new instance every time. Because now you have only 160 of whatever type `timeslot` have and `timeslot` array store references for them.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you clarify that. This is how I initialized timeslots: Timeslot[] timeslot = new Timeslot[160000];

Comment: How you initialize `timeslot_build`?

Comment: Ah, I understand what you mean but that's actually what I want. I want timeslot[0*160 + i] = timeslot[1*160 + i] = timeslot[2*160 + i], only the weeks should differ.

Comment: You can't have one instance have different values in it field.

Comment: `timeslot[0*160 + i]` = `timeslot[1*160 + i]` mean they refer to single instance.